# Firebase auth user.getIdToken() sending expired tokens

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, axios, firebase-admin

As far as I know, getIdToken() should by default send an unexpired token to the server, handling the token refreshing internally. However, I am getting many many errors from my server regarding expired tokens.

On my frontend, I created axios instance as follows:

```
const base = axios.create({
  baseURL: apiUrl,
});

base.interceptors.request.use(async (config) => {
  const token = await getAccessToken();
  config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
  return config;
});

const getAccessToken = async () => {
  const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
  if (user) {
    const token = await user.getIdToken();
    return token;
  }
  return null;
};
```

Then on the receiving server, I verify the token by doing:

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

const auths = req.headers.authorization.split(" ");
admin.auth().verifyIdToken(auths[1]).then(async token => {
  ...
});
```

The error I receive from the server is:

`Error: Firebase ID token has expired. Get a fresh ID token from your client app and try again (auth/id-token-expired). See https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens for details on how to retrieve an ID token.`

If I change `getIdToken()` to `getIdToken(true)`, the issue goes away.

I verified that the getAccessToken method is called for every request made. I'm a bit lost why my server continues to complain about expired tokens, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is it using role based authentication

Comment: Nope, we're not using role-based auth.

Comment: What server code are you calling? And what's the exact error message you get?

Comment: Sorry I should've been clearer, I have updated the question, thanks!

Comment: Double check your server clock is correct. It is highly likely the clock being off is the root cause of this.

Comment: My apps are hosted on GAE/GKE, I assumed their times are already correct.